# splitting a LinkedList

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures, linked-list

Say I have a linked-list such as `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`. I want to split this linked-list from the first element to `m`<sub>th</sub> element and from `m+1`<sub>th</sub> to the end, so for `m=2` we'd have `1 -> 2` and `3 -> 4 -> 5`, something like this:

```
private ListNode split(ListNode head, int m) {
    ListNode h1 = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode h2 = new ListNode(0);

    h1.next = head;
    h2.next = head;   // same reference: error!

    ListNode cur1 = h1;
    ListNode cur2 = h2;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cur1 = cur1.next;
    }
    cur1.next = null;

    ListNode tmp = cur2.next;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
    cur2.next = tmp;

    // doesn't matter which one to return
    return h2.next;
}
```

I know this is not working because I am using the same reference (`head`) for my `h2` and I need to make a copy of the head (`h2.next = copyOfHead`), but I wonder if there is a better, more efficient solution without making a copy of head.

Comment: @phonetagger C#, Java, doesn't matter

Comment: For starters, I think you want `Listnode h1 = head; Listnode h2 = head;` rather than the first four lines you currently have.

Comment: @BobKaufman as phonetagger pointed out, this is a sub-problem from a puzzle I'm working on. Changing those lines doesn't really change the question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need one Node reference to the head

Starting from the head, if you modify the "starting" list so the `n`-th node points at null (thereby "splitting"), you then return the `n+1` Node, which has the remainder of the list.

I'm imagining something like this

```
private ListNode split(ListNode head, int m) {

    ListNode tmp = head;
    // Additionally check that you don't go beyond the list
    for (int i = 0; tmp.next != null && i < m; i++) {
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }

    ListNode remainder = tmp.next;
    tmp.next = null;

    return remainder;
}
```